# Attempting to use com.android.future.usb.UsbAccessory & UsbManager namespaces

Tags: c#, android, xamarin.android

At this site we found relevant information about the Framework to use:  (we decided on using Android 2.3)

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/usb/accessory.html

> com.android.future.usb: To support USB accessory mode in Android 2.3.4, the Google APIs add-on library includes the backported USB accessory APIs and they are contained in this namespace. Android 3.1 also supports importing and calling the classes within this namespace to support applications written with the add-on library. This add-on library is a thin wrapper around the android.hardware.usb accessory APIs and does not support USB host mode. If you want to support the widest range of devices that support USB accessory mode, use the add-on library and import this package. It is important to note that not all Android 2.3.4 devices are required to support the USB accessory feature. Each individual device manufacturer decides whether or not to support this capability, which is why you must declare it in your manifest file.

Also under the section **Choosing the Right USB Accessory APIs** it states that you should use Android 2.3.4 or Android 3.1 APIs.

We are attempting to use the following code in a basic test program to see if we can connect to a USB device on a Sumsung Droid phone.

**C# code:**

```
UsbManager deviceManager = null;
UsbAccessory[] accessories = null;
UsbAccessory accessory = null;
```

We tried #using Android.Hardware; in VS 2010.

1) Is this possible?
2) How do you get access to the Android usb namespace?

We have a lot of C# code that we would like to reuse so writing the app in Java is not our first choice.  Any ideas? Thank You!

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the MonoDroid API, it looks like you need Android.Hardware.Usb namespace.  Here's a link to the API reference where I found it.  I haven't tested it yet though.

http://docs.xamarin.com/android/api

Comment: Android.Hardware.Usb Namespace Provides support to communicate with USB hardware peripherals that are connected to Android-powered devices... Use UsbDevice to communicate with the hardware peripheral if the Android-powered device is acting as the USB host. Use UsbAccessory if the peripheral is acting as the USB host. ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ **Unfortunately, C# does not allow .Usb after Hardware namespace. We tried this also.**

Comment: This may be of some interest also: VS 2010 only allows selecting frameworks (Android 1.6, 2.1, 2.2, & 2.3)… If 3 or 4 is needed we cannot figure a way to boost this higher.

Comment: I deleted my comment because I now have build errors with that namespace.  Doing more research today for a project, will report back.

Comment: Found this: http://developer.android.com/sdk/android-2.3.4.html

...The library exposes a framework API that lets applications discover, communicate with, and manage a variety of device types connected over USB. It also provides the implementation of the API against parts of the Android platform that are not directly exposed to applications in Android 2.3.4.

Comment: I've not made any progress with Mono, however the libraries are sort of working natively.  Best bet would be contacting Xamarin about the issue.

Comment: This is what we got back from Xamarin: UsbManager support is only available through the Android SDK for Android 3.1 (Level 12). Google provided a third party library you could use with Android 2.3.4 to provide UsbManager use with that version of the OS but we do not yet have an easy way of exposing third party libraries (this is something we are working hard to support). You can manually create bindings to the library yourself using JNI (this is how we would support it in the future except we are working on a generator that makes these binds almost automatic to create).